# Measuring the resolution of `std::clock()`

Tags: c++, clock

Is it possible to measure the resolution of the `std::clock()` call? Or is this a problem where observing without influencing isn't possible?

I wrote the following naive benchmark:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::clock_t initial = std::clock();
    std::clock_t current;
    while (initial == (current = std::clock()));
    std::cout << "Initial: " << initial << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Current: " << current << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Precision: " << (static_cast<double>(current - initial) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << "s" << std::endl;
}
```

I've run it a few hundred times and it always outputs `0.01s`.

My questions are:

- Is above code a good way to measure the resolution of `clock()`?
- If no then what is wrong with it? And how could it be improved?

Comment: What do you mean by "accuracy"? How will you measure that without referring to another, "proper" clock?

Comment: Does it break on the first loop everytime?

Comment: @Kerrek SB you're paraphrasing my question.

Comment: @James it takes 50000-100000 iterations (unoptimized).

Comment: You get the resolution of the clock, not the precision. Obviously the clock ticks 10 ms at a time, but we don't know correct that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, sort of.  Something like what you're doing is a good first
approximation.  But I'm not sure how useful it is: it determines the
resolution, but it still doesn't tell you anything about the accuracy;
under Windows, for example, `clock` is so inaccurate as to render it
useless.